# Get String in between either single quotes or empty space

Tags: java, regex

I wish to have a regular expression which gives me the name of classLoader inserted in single quotes/empty-space but not a mixture of both.
i.e. some examples. :

> 2014-05-21 22:05:13.685 TRACE [Core]
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3 searching for resource
>   'java/util/LoggerFactory.class'.

expected output `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3`

> 2014-05-21 22:05:13.685 TRACE [Core] Class
>   'org.jboss.weld.metadata.TypeStore' not found in classloader
>   'org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader@4ebded0b'.

expected output `org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader@4ebded0b`

> 2014-05-21 22:04:34.591 INFO  [Core] Started plugin
>   org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.IntegrationPlugin from
>   /Users/endragor/Downloads/jrebel/jrebel.jar in
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3

expected output `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3`

Note that for last exampe, the line ends with new line character. i.e. there is nothing in front.

This is what I have tried `".*[\\s|'](.*ClassLoader.*[^']*)['|\\s].*"`. But it doesn't work. For the first example it gives below rather than `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3`:

> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3 searching for resource
>   'java/util/LoggerFactory.class

Also my regex does not handle if the class loader string is end of the line i.e. example-3 above. What can I do so that either `'` is considered or `\\s` but not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this regex should do without grouping:

```
[^\s']*ClassLoader[^\s']*
```

in java it should be:

```
[^\\s']*ClassLoader[^\\s']*
```

you don't need the pipe `|` in `[..]`, in regex `[abcd]` means `a or b or c or d`

#### update

add java codes:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\s']*ClassLoader[^\\s']*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("2014-05-21 22:05:13.685 TRACE [Core] sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3 searching for resource 'java/util/LoggerFactory.class'.");
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
```

output:

```
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62c8aeb3
```

Comment: I need grouping because I need to extract the name of ClassLoader.

Comment: Thanks for the help :). But the above one doesn't match :(

Comment: @Jatin did you write java code correctly? see update, I added java codes for your example1.

Comment: Oops. It doesn't work with this: 2014-05-21 22:05:10.583 INFO  [Core] org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader@4ebded0b instrumented class 'com.spirent.rlm.core.app.internal.StatelessService' from 'Virtual Resource [com/spirent/rlm/core/app/internal/StatelessService.class, Dir [/Users/endragor/Work/ilo/iTestLabOptimizer/src/rlm-core/target/classes, []]]'.

Comment: i.e. If i do m.find with above string, it returns false

Comment: @Jatin here I tested with same codes as I posted, just replace the string, I got output: `org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader@4ebded0b`

Comment: Sorry Sorry. My fault. I had done a typo. Its working correct. I really appreciate the help. It took me quite sometime to make one. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

```
String extractedValue=yourString.replaceAll("(.*)([ '])(.*ClassLoader.*?)(\\2)(.*)", "$3");
```

Whenever we want to extract String between a predifined set of value , where the first and last delimiter should have the same value , we can use [Backreference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html#backref) feature .

Comment: because there is no space in the end of the String i think

Comment: Yup :) We need to handle that case also

Comment: But what does \\2 mean?

Comment: it's a backreference to the second group `([ '])` , take a look at the link in my answer.

Comment: if you want to handle the case where there is no space also then add `*` after `(\\2)` .

Answer (score 1):

As operator has changed the original post so here is the updated answer.

Simply use below pattern to check for **default `toString()` representation of `Object`** class.

```
[\w\.$]+ClassLoader@[a-z0-9]+
```

Pattern Expiation:

```
\w      A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]
X+      X, one or more times

[abc]   a, b, or c (simple class)
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Here is the [DEMO](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PGaiQDgnj2zkJu8v)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question :) String after --> is the answer I expect from the before string.